Issue in creating a screen sharing app on electron
I am trying to create an electron app in which I want to share user desktop screen to a web app. The desktop user has to just give the permission of screen recording to the desktop app. The other user from the web can then see the desktop user screen.
Is there any way I can achieve this?
I tried electron desktop capturer api and webrtc for this but the web app also asking for the camera permission which I don't want to ask from the web app. Only the desktop app should ask for this permission and send the stream to the web app.
